# Writing bits to file?

Tags: c++, binary, ofstream, huffman-code

I'm trying to implement a Huffman tree.

Content of my simple .txt file that I want to do a simple test:

```
aaaaabbbbccd
```

Frequencies of characters: a:5, b:4, c:2, d:1

Code Table: (Data type of **1**s and **0**s: **string**)

```
a:0
d:100
c:101
b:11
```

Result that I want to write as binary: (22 bits)

```
0000011111111101101100
```

How can I write ***bit-by-bit*** each character of this result as a binary to ".dat" file? (not as string)

Comment: You want to create a file containing just these 22 bits?

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes.

Comment: Your code table has a bit of a problem

Comment: you can write only complete bytes, i.e. 8 bit chunks. You could add a header byte indicating how many bits of the last byte are valid, or you could introduce a "stop character", like the `'\0'` in strings and encode this like the other characters.

Comment: And you cannot create a file that doesn't contain whole bytes, so the number of bit must be a multiple of 8

Comment: @leyanpan: That's not a very helpful comment w/o even a hint as to what problem you refer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP asked:

> How can I write bit-by-bit each character of this result as a binary to ".dat" file? (not as string)

You can not and here is why...

---

> **Memory model**
>
> Defines the semantics of a computer memory storage for the purpose of C++ abstract machine.
>
> The memory available to a C++ program is one or more contiguous sequences of *`bytes`*. Each byte in memory has a unique *address*.
>
> **Byte**
>
> A *`byte`* is the smallest addressable unit of memory. It is defined as a contiguous sequence of bits, large enough to hold the value of any UTF-8 code unit (256 distinct values) and of `(since C++14)` any member of the *basic execution character set* (the 96 characters that are required to be `single-byte`). Similar to C, C++ supports `bytes` of sizes 8 bits and greater.
>
> The types `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` use one byte for both storage and value representation. The number of bits in a byte is accessible as `CHAR_BIT` or `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits`.

Compliments of `cppreference.com`

You can find this page here: [cppreference:memory model](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model)

---

This comes from the 2017-03-21: standard

> ©ISO/IEC N4659
>
> **4.4 The C++ memory model**     **[intro.memory]**
>
> 1. The fundamental storage unit in the C++ memory model is the *byte*. A byte is at least large enough to contain any member of the basic execution character set (5.3) and the eight-bit code units of the Unicode UTF-8 encoding form and is composed of a contiguous sequence of bits,<sup>4</sup> the number of which is implementation-defined. The least significant bit is called the *low-order bit*; the most significant bit is called the *high-order bit*. The memory available to a C++ program consists of one or more sequences of contiguous bytes. Every byte has a unique address.
> 2. [ *Note*: The representation of types is described in 6.9. —*end note* ]
> 3. A *memory location* is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having nonzero width. [ *Note*: Various features of the language, such as references and virtual functions, might involve additional memory locations that are not accessible to programs but are managed by the implementation. —*end note* ] Two or more threads of execution (4.7) can access separate memory locations without interfering
>      with each other.
> 4. [ *Note*: Thus a bit-field and an adjacent non-bit-field are in separate memory locations, and therefore can be concurrently updated by two threads of execution without interference. The same applies to two bit-fields, if one is declared inside a nested struct declaration and the other is not, or if the two are separated by a zero-length bit-field declaration, or if they are separated by a non-bit-field declaration. It is not safe to concurrently update two bit-fields in the same struct if all fields between them are also bit-fields of nonzero width. —*end note* ]
> 5. [ *Example*: A structure declared as
>
>    ```
>    struct {
>        char a;
>        int b:5,
>        c:11,
>        :0,
>        d:8;
>        struct {int ee:8;} e;
>    }
>    ```
>
>    contains four separate memory locations: The field a and bit-fields d and e.ee are each separate memory
>      locations, and can be modified concurrently without interfering with each other. The bit-fields b and c
>      together constitute the fourth memory location. The bit-fields b and c cannot be concurrently modified, but
>      b and a, for example, can be. —*end example* ]
>
>    ---
>
>    <sup>4) The number of bits in a byte is reported by the macro **CHAR_BIT** in the header `<climits>`.</sup>

This version of the standard can be found here: 
[www.open-std.org](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) section `§ 4.4`  on pages 8 & 9.

---

The smallest possible memory module that can be written to in a program is 8 contiguous bits or more for a standard byte. Even with bit fields, the `1 byte` requirement still holds. You can manipulate, toggle, set, individual bits within a `byte` but you can not write individual `bits`.

What can be done is to have a `byte` buffer with a count of bits written. When your required bits are written you will need to have the rest of the unused bits marked as `padding` or `un-used buffer bits`.

**Edit**

**[*Note:*]** -- When using `bit fields` or `unions` one thing that you must take into consideration is the `endian` of the specific architecture.

Answer (score 6):

Answer:  You can't.

The minimum amount you can write to a file (or read from it), is a `char` or `unsigned char`.  For all practical purposes, a char has exactly eight bits.

You are going to need to have a one char buffer, and a count of the number of bits it holds.  When that number reaches 8, you need to write it out, and reset the count to 0.  You will also need a way to flush the buffer at the end.  (Not that you *cannot* write 22 bits to a file - you can only write 16 or 24.  You will need some way to mark which bits at the end are unused.)

Something like:

```
struct BitBuffer {
    FILE* file; // Initialization skipped.
    unsigned char buffer = 0;
    unsigned count = 0;

    void outputBit(unsigned char bit) {
         buffer <<= 1;         // Make room for next bit.
         if (bit) buffer |= 1; // Set if necessary.
         count++;              // Remember we have added a bit.
         if (count == 8) {
             fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, file); // Error handling elided.
             buffer = 0;
             count = 0;
         }
    }
};
```

Comment: @Murat: Sorry about that!  I have used `sizeof(buffer)`, because it is `buffer` you writing out.  The fact that `bit` is the same size is irrelevant.  Alternatively, you could write this as 1, because `sizeof(unsigned char)` is *defined* to be 1 (but using the constant means that you couldn't optimize by changing buffer to `uint64_t`).

Answer (score 0):

### Answer: You can, in a way.

Hello, from my experience I have found a way to do that simple. For the task you need to define yourself and array of characters (it just needs to be for instance 1 byte, it can be bigger). After that you must define functions to access a specific bit from any element. For example, how to write an expression to get the value of the 3th bit from a char in C++.

```
*/*position is [1,..,n], and bytes 
are in little endian and index from 0`enter code here`*/
int bit_at(int position, unsigned char byte)
{
  return (byte & (1 << (position - 1)));
}*
```

Now you can vision the array of bytes as this
[b1,...,bn]

Now what we actually have in memory is 8 * n bits of memory
We can try to visualize it like so.
NOTE: the arrays is zeroed!
|0000 0000|0000 0000|...|0000 0000|

Now from this you or whoever wants can figure how to manipulate it to get a specific bit from this array. Of course there will be some sort of converted but that is not such a problem.
In the end, for the encoding you provide, that is:
a:0
d:100
c:101
b:11

We can encode the message "abcd",
and make an array that holds the bits
of the message, using the elements
of the array as arrays for bits, like so:

|0111 0110|0000 0000|

You can write this to memory and you will have an excess of at most 7 bits.
This is a simple example, but it can be extended into much more.
I hope this gave some answers to your question.